# Можно ли создать массив с указателями сразу наобъекты 2 класса? С++

Tags: массивы, ооп, классы, указатели

У меня есть два класса : Маги и обычные персонажи, не обладающие магией. Мне нужно создать массив на 10 указателях на объекты этих классов и занести в
него адреса объектов обоих классов. Возможно ли это вообще? Не могу додуматься до того как такое реализовать

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вам надо просто завести указатель на двумерный массив.

`n` - в вашем случае количество классов (маг / не маг)

`M` - 10

```
int** Mas = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        Mas[i] = new int [m];
```

Comment: точно! спасибо большое

Comment: @eve Только не забудьте после работы с динамическим массивом удалить его)

Comment: это само собой разумеющееся ;)